# Passing value from child class to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A package is made of an expense, revenue, and balance which are based on the sales which are made of an amount. How would I add up each `@sale.amount` into `@package.revenue`?

Model package.rb:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
end
```

Model sale.rb:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :packages do
    resources :sales do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you formulate the relation between `@sale.amount` and `@package.revenue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord has a handy [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method for calculating the sum of the values in a column:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales

  def revenue
    sales.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

Note that while it looks similar to `sales.map(&:amount).sum` its performance will be vastly better because ActiveRecord will let the database do the calculation and then retrieve only a single value (the final sum) from the database, whereas the other method will fetch every associated record from the database (of which there may be many thousands), instantiate a Sale object for each one, then get the `amount` from each Sale object and finally calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales

  def revenue
    sales.map(&:amount).sum
  end
end
```

Comment: maybe provide an example that matches the title of the question ?